# Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame in a tabular form. I am trying to format it in the attached format but failing miserably. I have tried versions of for loop but nothing is working out. Would appreciate any help.

P.S : the dates are randomly generated but do show the gist of what I am trying to achieve

[This is what the DataFrame looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiYFN.png)

[*This is what I want it to look like*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZq5E.png)

Comment: Please share with us, any code that you have so far.

Comment: nowhere actually, I have been stuck at this one sadly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a rough sketch of the code.. needs to be editted a little bit if the data changes, but please check if this helps..

```
import pandas as pd

dfsrc = pd.DataFrame(columns=['customer', 'date'], index=None)
customer_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
date_list = ['10/02/2020', '27/01/2020', '27/04/2020', '26/03/2020', '21/02/2020', '07/06/2020', '12/04/2020', '29/05/2020', '10/05/2020', '08/06/2020']
dfsrc.customer = customer_list
dfsrc.date = date_list

results = []
purchases = ['first_purchase', 'second_purchase', 'third_purchase']

for cust in dfsrc.customer.unique():
    rows = dfsrc[dfsrc.customer == cust].reset_index()
    cust_dict = {}
    cust_dict['customer'] = cust
    for idx, row in rows.iterrows():
        cust_dict[purchases[idx]] = row['date']
    results.append(cust_dict)

dfdest = pd.DataFrame(data=results, columns=['customer', 'first_purchase', 'second_purchase', 'third_purchase'])
dfdest
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, I used a modified version of this and it worked like a charm

Comment: the only issue is speed, df is about 15 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new column for each new purchase, I think it is better to use single column, and have an incremental value for subsequent purchase for the same individual.

Using the dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
                      , 'Date_of_Purchase': ['10/02/2020', '27/01/2020', '27/04/2020', '26/03/2020', '21/02/2020',
                                             '07/06/2020', \
                                             '12/04/2020', '29/05/2020']})
```

First sort the column customer base on customer name:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Customer'], inplace=True)
```

Then,incremental the number of purchase using the code below:

```
df['n_purchase_times'] = df.groupby(['Customer']).cumcount() + 1
```

which give you

```
  Customer Date_of_Purchase  n_purchase_times
0        a       10/02/2020                 1
4        a       21/02/2020                 2
1        b       27/01/2020                 1
5        b       07/06/2020                 2
2        c       27/04/2020                 1
6        c       12/04/2020                 2
3        d       26/03/2020                 1
7        d       29/05/2020                 2
```

Comment: If my or another [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks